# How do you save to three collections at once?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm building my first mean stack app.  It's a review site that contains three models:  User, Review, and Company.

When I make a review, I want the new review to be saved to the 'review' collection, and for that review to be connected by reference to the company being reviewed and the user who wrote the review.  I also want the user to hold a reference to the review, and the company to hold a reference to all the reviews it has.  Here are my models:

**Review**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const reviewSchema = new Schema ({

  companyName: String,
  companyId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company'},
  starRating: Number,
  subject: String,
  commentBody: String,
  createdBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},

});


const Review = mongoose.model("Review", reviewSchema);
module.exports = Review;
```

**Company**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const companySchema = new Schema ({

  companyName: String,
  about: String,
  basedIn: String,
  materialOrigins: [String],
  productRange: [String],
  category: String,
  reviews: [ {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review'} ],
  socialRating: Number,
  environmentalRating: Number,
  priceRange: Number

});


const Company = mongoose.model("Company", companySchema);
module.exports = Company;
```

**User**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema ({
  email: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  password: String,
  image: Object,
  aboutText: String,
  reviews: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Review" } ]
  // comments: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }

});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

This is my current route, which currently saves the review to the collection and attaches the user.  However, the user doesn't get the review.

**route**

```
router.post('/:category/:company', (req, res) => {

  var subject = req.body.subject;
  var commentBody = req.body.commentBody;
  var starRating = req.body.starRating;
  var userId = req.body.userId;

  if(!subject || !commentBody || !starRating) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Subject, comment body, and star rating are required." });
    return;
  }

  var newReview = Review({
    starRating,
    subject,
    commentBody,
    userId
  });


     User.findById(userId, {
     }, (err, user) => {
       if (err) {
         return res.send(err);
       } else {

         console.log("checking out user in route", user);
         user.reviews.push(newReview);
         user.save();

         newReview.save((err, review) => {
              if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: err });
              } else {
                res.status(200).json({ message: 'Review saved', review });
              }
            });

       }
     });
```

I haven't tried adding the company in because I'm trying to do one thing at a time.  I've been looking at 'populate', but all of the documentation seems to only use two models at once.  Is it possible to do three at once?  Or am I overcomplicating this?

Apologies if this is all overcomplicated.  I'm fairly new to MongoDB and MEAN stack in general.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it, for any people landing on this page wondering the same thing in the future.

Here's my route:

```
router.post('/:category/:company', (req, res, next) => {

  var companyName;
  var companyId;

  var subject = req.body.subject;
  var commentBody = req.body.commentBody;
  var starRating = req.body.starRating;
  var createdBy = req.body.createdBy;


  if(!subject || !commentBody || !starRating) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Subject, comment body, and star rating are required." });
    return;
  }

  var newReview = Review({
    starRating,
    subject,
    commentBody,
    createdBy
  });

 //I need the companyId and companyInfo for later use in my review save.  I'm calling the company with the name I have from my params, and setting the id and name with the received data from Mongo.

  Company.findOne({"companyName": req.params.company}, (err, company) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: err });
    } else {
      this.companyName = company.companyName;
      this.companyId = company.id;
    }
  });

         newReview.save((err, review) => {

//Push the review id to the user
              if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: err });
              } else { User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: createdBy },{$push:  {reviews: review.id} }, (err) => {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log("There was an error pushing review to user");
                    next(err);
//Push the review id to the company
                  } else {  Company.findOneAndUpdate({ "companyName": req.params.company}, {$push: {reviews: review.id}}, (err, company) => {
                      if (err) {
                        console.log("There was an error pushing review to company");
                        next(err);
                      } else {

                        //Updates the review by setting companyId and companyName properties to review for Mongo
                        Review.update({_id: review.id}, {$set: {companyId: this.companyId, companyName: this.companyName}}, (err, changes) => {
                          if(err) {
                            return res.status(400).json({message : err});
                          } else {
                            console.log("updating review successfully with company info", changes);
                          }
                        });

                        console.log ("Review successfully saved");

                        res.json({
                          review: review,
                        });

            }
          });

        }
      });

    }


});
});
```

If anyone has feedback on how this could be done better/more efficiently, let me know.  Cheers.